# How to fix Y-Axis range in d3.js graphs

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a parallel coordinates graph and developing based on http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281 example. In that i need the Y-axis fixed between 0 to 100. Could you please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
      x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
        return d != "name" && d != "group" && d != "id" &&
               d != "Eqid" && d != "Src" && d != "Datetime" && d != "Region" &&   // Earthquake csv
               (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0.0,100])
            .range([h, 0]));
      }));
```

In the domain please add the range.

Change the y domain to each dimension to [0,100]. In the example, it's running a loop to find the extent of each dimension instead.